# Django pytest-selenium functional tests

Tags: django, selenium, functional-testing

I've created the tests folder, written my first test that should open a browser, point to a page and login, then go to home page.

Test run and fail, as expected, but I can't find out why.

*browser* should be available, pytest-selenium is installed by pip.

```
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission, User
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

class CreaPageTest(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
  def test_homepage(self):
    request = self.client.get('/new')
    request.user = self.user
    self.assertEqual(request.status_code, 200)

  def test_login(self):
    request = self.client.get('/per/login')

    username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
    username_field.send_keys('peppa')

    password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
    password_field.send_keys('pig')
    password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    test_homepage()


>       username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
E       AttributeError: 'CreaPageTest' object has no attribute 'browser'

tests/test_ore_app_views.py:27: AttributeError
```

what am I missing?
Any advice to examples of this kind of test is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure self.browser inside setUp function. You are also missing an import for `Keys`. Code should be like this.

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission, User
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory

class CreaPageTest(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Also please refer to the docs, here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html